# Generate pips on a die based on value

Tags: algorithms, javascript, graphics

Is there an algorithm to generate the pips on a die or domino?

I know that there is usually an odd number of columns and even number of rows (unless the max number of pips is not a perfect root).

[image]

At this time, I have a lookup map which stores where the pips are located on the face, based on the count. If you would like to see a running example of the code below, you can try it out [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6n0dftz/16/).

### Code

```js
var faces = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

// Main method
(function() {
  var rows = 3;
  var columns = 3;
  var canvasList = document.querySelectorAll('canvas[id^="die-"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < canvasList.length; i++) {
    drawDie(canvasList[i].getContext('2d'), i, faces, rows, columns);
  }
}());

function drawDie(context, count, faces, rows, columns) {
  var width = context.canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = context.canvas.clientHeight;
  drawBackground(context, width, height);
  if (count > 0) {
    drawPips(context, width, height, count, faces, rows, columns);
  }
}

function drawBackground(context, width, height) {
  context.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
  context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
  roundRect(context, 0, 0, width, height, width * 0.2, true, true);
}

function drawPips(context, width, height, count, faces, rows, columns) {
  var x = measure(width, columns, 0.05);
  var y = measure(height, rows, 0.05);
  var radius = Math.min(x.off, y.off) * 0.33;
  var hue = randRange(0, 360);
  var fill = hslToHex(hue, 0.85, 0.55);
  var stroke = hslToHex(hue, 0.85, 0.33);
  var pipMap = faces[count];
  var index = 0;

  for (var yPos = y.start; yPos < y.avail; yPos += y.off) {
    for (var xPos = x.start; xPos < x.avail; xPos += x.off) {
      if (pipMap[index++] === 1) {
        drawPip(context, xPos, yPos, radius, fill, stroke);
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawPip(context, x, y, radius, fill, stroke) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = fill;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = stroke;
  context.stroke();
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/3368118/1762224
function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {
  if (typeof stroke == 'undefined') stroke = true;
  if (typeof radius === 'undefined') radius = 5;
  if (typeof radius === 'number') {
    radius = {
      tl: radius,
      tr: radius,
      br: radius,
      bl: radius
    };
  } else {
    var defaultRadius = {
      tl: 0,
      tr: 0,
      br: 0,
      bl: 0
    };
    for (var side in defaultRadius) {
      radius[side] = radius[side] || defaultRadius[side];
    }
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius.tr, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius.tr);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius.br);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius.br, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius.bl);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius.tl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  if (fill) ctx.fill();
  if (stroke) ctx.stroke();
}

function measure(length, partitions, inset) {
  var pad = length * inset;
  var avail = length - (pad * 2);
  var off = avail / partitions;
  var start = pad + (off / 2);

  return {
    length: length,
    pad: pad,
    avail: avail,
    off: off,
    start: start
  };
}

function hslToRgb(h, s, l) {
  var m1, m2, hue;
  var r, g, b
  if (s == 0) r = g = b = (l * 255);
  else {
    if (l <= 0.5) m2 = l * (s + 1);
    else m2 = l + s - l * s;
    m1 = l * 2 - m2;
    hue = h / 360;
    r = Math.round(hueToRgb(m1, m2, hue + 1 / 3));
    g = Math.round(hueToRgb(m1, m2, hue));
    b = Math.round(hueToRgb(m1, m2, hue - 1 / 3));
  }
  return [r, g, b];
}

function hueToRgb(m1, m2, hue) {
  var v;
  if (hue < 0) hue += 1;
  else if (hue > 1) hue -= 1;

  if (6 * hue < 1) v = m1 + (m2 - m1) * hue * 6;
  else if (2 * hue < 1) v = m2;
  else if (3 * hue < 2) v = m1 + (m2 - m1) * (2 / 3 - hue) * 6;
  else v = m1;

  return 255 * v;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return '#' + [].slice.apply(arguments).map(function(c) {
    return (function(hex) {
      return hex.length === 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
    }(Math.floor(c).toString(16)));
  }).join('');
}

function hslToHex(h, s, l) {
  return rgbToHex.apply(null, hslToRgb.apply(null, arguments));
}

function randRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="die-0" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-1" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-2" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-3" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-4" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-5" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-6" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-7" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-8" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
<canvas id="die-9" width="124" height="124"></canvas>
```

Comment: In all honesty, I'd be doing it as a lookup map too.

Comment: @MichaelT: Yes, a lookup is what I want to use, but I would like to know if there is an algorithm to generate the lookup that I have created, by hand, above. The algorithm should be able to generate a 1x1, 2x2, 3x2, 3x3, 3x4, or any COLxROW for that matter.

Comment: To whomever voted to migrate this question: algorithm questions are on-topic both here and at SO. The fact that it has code has no bearing on this, because it is looking for answers about the algorithm, not the code.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm becomes obvious if you just consider the even values. Fill in pairs of opposite corners until you run out of corners, then fill in opposite sides. For odd numbers, just add the center pip.

Answer (score 2):

One algorithm would be to break it down into things like:

- if n is odd, display the center pip
- if n >= 2, display the upper-right and lower-left pips
- if n >= 4, display the upper-left and lower-right pips
- if n >= 6, display the left-center and right-center pips
- if n >= 8, display the top-center and bottom-center pips

Honestly, though, it's just as easy to just have a list of pips for each number, as you have in your code.

Comment: But what if it were a 12 pip die? I want it to be dynamic. Is there a way to build the look up?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl how do *you* want the 12 pip dice to look?  3x4? 4x3? a 4x4 with 4 missing pips somewhere?

Comment: Since 12 is not a perfect square, it should have even rows and odd columns. So 3 columns by 4 rows. That is basically in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use pips for large numbers? After 9, the users will be spending a lot of time counting pips one-by-one. Notice that in real life, dice with sides > 6 use digits rather than pips for exactly this reason.

Comment: Well, have you seen a double-sided 12 and 15 domino set? Same concept. Sorry for not including that detail...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl and a 15 is a 4x3 + 3 (which I think is rather inelegant). However, I'd *still* do it for a lookup table up to 15.  I would point out that rarely do you see a 15 set that isn't colored now days - people do the color matching more easily than pip count matching.

Comment: There's a reason why polyhedral dice used in RPGs (e.g., 12-sided dice, 20-sided dice) have numerals stamped on them rather than a large number of pips.